# MySQL merge rows with same ID while preserving timestamps

Tags: mysql, join, merge, timestamp

I have the following table with data:

Table 1:

```
ID          START_DATE                 END_DATE
--          ----------                 --------
1        2016-08-20 00:01:00              NULL
1        2016-08-20 00:02:00              NULL
1              NULL                2016-08-20 00:03:00
1              NULL                2016-08-20 00:04:00
```

I would like to "merge" the data for the unique ID 1 so that I can easily read it. It should look like the following (basically grabbing the earliest timestamp for START_DATE and latest timestamp for END_DATE):

Table 2:

```
ID         START_DATE                 END_DATE
--         ----------                 --------
1      2016-08-20 00:01:00       2016-08-20 00:04:00
```

This is ultimately so that I can determine if the following TX_ID record falls within the START_DATE and END_DATE and set the FALL_WITHIN_START_AND_END parameter to True.

Table 3:

```
TX_ID         TIMESTAMP          FALL_WITHIN_START_AND_END
-----         ---------          -------------------------
123456    2016-08-20 00:02:35              True
```

Could someone recommend a MySQL query to "merge" Table 1 value so that it would look like Table 2? This is so I can more easily determine if the TX_ID in Table 3 falls within the complete start and end date range.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barmar has a fine approach for the first part of your question.  But, for the full answer, you can use `exists`:

```
select t3.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table1 t1
                          where t1.id = t3.id and t1.start_date <= t3.timestamp
                         ) and
                  exists (select 1
                          from table1 t1
                          where t1.id = t3.id and t1.end_date >= t3.timestamp
                         ) 
             then 1 else 0
        end) as fall_within_start_and_end 
from table3 t3;
```

The advantage of this approach over the `group by` is that it can take advantage of indexes on `table1(id, start_date)` and `table1(id, end_date)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple `GROUP BY` using the `MIN` and `MAX` function.

```
SELECT id, MIN(start_date) AS start_date, MAX(end_date) AS end_date
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id
```